# Un-hide an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two options for select. I am trying to get it to where if the user selects "Case Manager" for option for select #1, then option for select #2 appears (it is currently hidden from the user).

Haml:

```
= form_tag app_configurations_path, :method=> 'put' do |f|
  -@all_configurations.each do |config|
      =hidden_field_tag "config_ids[]", config.id
      %label= t('workflow.duplicate_claim_manager')
      = select_tag('duplicate_claim[case_manager]', options_for_select(@case_managers_drop_down, config.configuration_value),name: "config[#{config.id}]", :include_blank => true)

      %label.hidden(for="duplicate_claim_manager_secondary")
      = hidden_field('duplicate_claim_manager_secondary', options_for_select(@case_managers_drop_down, config.configuration_value),name: "config[#{config.id}]", :include_blank => true)
```

The Haml appears to be correct, but I can't get the Javascript to correctly unhide option for select #2. Any ideas?

```
if ($("#duplicate_claim_case_manager :selected").text() == "Case Manager") {
   $("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary).setAttribute(type => text)
}
```

Comment: do you want to show/hide an option or the select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using jQuery's awesome `.toggle()` method. By itself, it will hide an element if it's currently being shown and show it if it's currently being hidden. This isn't exactly what you want.

But `.toggle()` also has a secret power. You can pass it a boolean as an argument. If that boolean is truthy, then it will show the element and if it's falsey, it will hide the element.

You could keep the input as a text field the entire time and just hide it (using the `style="display: none;"` attribute) by default or with JavaScript on page load.

Then you could use some code like this:

```
var isCaseManager = $("#duplicate_claim_case_manager :selected").text() === "Case Manager";

$("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").toggle(isCaseManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is not right
`$("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary).setAttribute(type => text)`

**setAttribute syntax:**

> element.setAttribute(name, value);

To change an attribute use:
`$("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary).setAttribute("type", "text")`

**References:**

- [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

But to actually *hide* or *show* an element, you are better off changing the css `display` property - with jQuery that is:

`$("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").show()`

and

`$("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").hide()`;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was a simple transcription error, but you're missing a closing quote in the following block:

This:

```
if ($("#duplicate_claim_case_manager :selected").text() == "Case Manager") {
    $("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary).setAttribute(type => text)
}
```

Should be this:

```
if ($("#duplicate_claim_case_manager :selected").text() == "Case Manager") {
    $("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").setAttribute(type => text); //Added closing quotation mark
}
```

To make an object visible, remove the display css attribute or set it to your desired mode.  To make an object invisible set its css display attribute to none.

Standard JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").style.display = "none"; //Hide
document.getElementById("duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").style.display = "";     //Make Visible
```

jQuery:

```
$("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").toggle(); // Toggle visibility

//Or...

$("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").show(); // Make Visible
$("#duplicate_claim_manager_secondary").hide(); // Hide
```